# git push makes me login to github. fatal: HttpRequestException encountered

Tags: git, github, httprequest, git-push

Every time I push my changes, no matter what branch I am on, it prompts for username. Once I type in my username an alert pops up prompting me to input my password. Once I do it, then changes are pushed. This just started happening and is annoying to type in my login info each time I push changes. Any suggestions?

> $ git push fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.    An error
>   occurred while sending the request. Username for 'https://github.com':
>   jhower

Answer (score 5):

jhower,

Update to the latest git and it should fix the issue.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/488

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you need to download and install the latest version of the Git Windows Credential Manager.

   Here is the link to it on GitHub. https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest
2. Restart your machine

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio integration with git, try following after installing git credential manager in the following link(https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/latest)

copy all files in `$env:USERPROFILE\bin\*.*` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\libexec\git-core`.

You may need admin privilege.