# "fatal: HttpRequestException encountered." Error with GitHub/Bitbucket Repositories due to dropping TLS-1.0 support

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, tls1.2, tls1.0

## Problem

I recently encountered the following message when I pushed to a GitHub repo:

`"fatal: HttpRequestException encountered. "`
followed by being prompted for my username and password again.

From previous searches, [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956927/cant-push-git-visual-studio-git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-fatal-httprequeste) and [various others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021981/git-push-makes-me-login-to-github-fatal-httprequestexception-encountered) have the same root problem. For those lazier than I am, a summary of the various solutions for different applications/OS are here with relevant discussions. Hopefully people find this helpful.

## Reason

Can't really call updating sercurity a problem, so here's the reason. The issue is GitHub has removed TLS-1.0 support which is causing the problem with clients including Microsoft Visual Studio's built in git client, versions of Git below 1.14 as well as GUI clients includint tortoiseGit, etc. The full release notes can be found here: 
https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-tlsv1-tlsv1-1-2018-12-01) will drop TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 starting 1 Dec 2018. I expect similar problems as before.

## Solution

Edit: moved my self-answer to an answer box. See below.

Comment: You should edit this and move the answer into an actual, separate answer. Self-answering is fine, but you've posted a question including the answer, all in the question box.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Git hub has removed TLS-1.0 from it's authentication services. https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

## Solutions

### Windows Clients

Use Version 2.14.3 (or newer) of Git for Windows and newer include an up-to-date Git Credential Manager for Windows: https://gitforwindows.org/

You can also explicitly update your Git Windows Credential Manager to the latest version, 1.14.0, to get TLS-1.2 support: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.14.0

### Visual Studio Clients

It is suggested to update your client to VS 2017 or, if you cannot upgrade, there are two machine-wide registry keys you can set that affect all .NET-based applications on the client machine that you can change... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html

### JDK

TLS-1.2 is default in JDK8 and available in JDK7.
https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https

### Red Hat native Git clients

RH 5 does not support TLS-1.2 and GitHubEngineering suggest updating to newer versions of the OS. RH 6.8 and 7.2 will support TLS-1.2. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/mensawater-183304/rhel5-wont-support-tlsv1-1-or-higher-36951/

Comment: This wasn't a complete solution for me. I use Git 2.15, which uses TLS 1.2. My server is Bitbucket so this might not apply to Github, but: The git operations succeed but _still_ print "fatal: HttpRequestException encountered", so they look like failures. Verbose output shows:
```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< ...
* Closing connection 0
fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
```
... followed by a HTTPS request that works.
Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: Hi @TravisWilson, if you haven't gotten this figured out by now... was anything on the Bitbucket announcement page useful?

Comment: I didn't see anything on the announcement that helped here. I haven't tried too hard to fix it since the git operations _do_ succeed. I (regrettably) got used to ignoring the error messages.

Comment: What is the path for your repository origin? is it http:// instead of https? Just an odd passing thought when wondering why git would try to use HTTP instead of https when you push/pull... P.S. Don't answer the first question.

Comment: Hi. I can't upgrade my git from version 2.8.2 to latest. I still got the 2.8.2 version after running `git --version`. Been searching for hours but nothing.

Comment: @LekzFlores, Can you elaborate on what you've done? I don't know how to help if I don't know what you've done and what system(s) you're working with. It may also be that you may also need to create your own question as this now seems to a problem with installing git instead of the TLS-1.0 support. Presumably, you're trying to implement one of the solutions above.

Comment: I have 2.15 git client, getting same error. I was able to download and switch branch but when i hit `git pull` i get the error. Maybe because the client asks the UN in same commandline window but password it asks in a separate dialog box. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

TLS support is discontinued in older versions of git.

Upgrading git on your machine solves this problem.

[Download the latest git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and install for your machine from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads.

Answer (score -3):

Above solution does not work for me.
But I have a solution for this,
When git asks us for username again on git bash, enter your GITHUB username and password on git bash itself and you will be back on work.

Comment: If it worked the second time, then this is unrelated to the question posed, which is about TLS 1.0 compatibility.

Comment: that is a thing, that github often asks... that is not a plausible answer to this question