# error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number

Tags: git

I can not clone any github repositories with https, but it is ok to clone a bitbucket/gitlab repository.

`git clone git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git`
it works.

`git clone http://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`
it works,too.

`git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`
I got this error:

```
Cloning into 'xxx'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': error:1400410B:SSL 
routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Any suggestions/insights are much appreciated.

Note: I can clone the repository with *SourceTree* client

Comment: Of those three URLs, the one starting with `https://` is the only one that uses SSL. The error says that your client's SSL does not like your server's SSL. Whether that means your client is wrong, or your server is wrong, or they just don't talk to each other, we can't tell from here (but since the server is GitHub, they're generally considered "right" by definition :-) ). You might look to see if there's an update available for whatever provides SSL on your client.

Comment: What OS and what version of git? Try to upgrade git. The problem is old OpenSSL version that [cannot establis secure connection with Github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109825/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

~/.gitconfig

Remove the following

```sh
# .gitcofig
[http "https://github.com"]
    proxy = https://127.0.0.1:1087
[https "https://github.com"]
    proxy = https://127.0.0.1:1087
```